# Unset POST values in php

Tags: php, post

acitvity.php

```
//Form start

   <form action=''>

   </form>

//Form End

//Get POST Values

<?php 

$_POST[''];

?>

//End
```

if i refresh the page after form is submitted, all the posted values are resubmitted, reason because all values are in browser so they are resubmitted. When i was searching solution for this, i got info that if the form & post operation done in separate php file then no more issue in posting values on refresh.

Is this the solutions? but now i have to do both in single file & POST values should not be submitted again on refresh.. is there any way to do this???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Learn PRG Pattern so that you can do this properly :)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

For example, you are trying to handle a user registration form, so what you do is you get a bunch of `POST`ed values, and save it into your database.

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
   // validate and save to db

   // get last inserted user_id
}
```

After you do that, instead of returning the same page with the previously `POST`ed values, you redirect the new user, for example to his profile page (assuming you have no activation requirement in place)

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
   // validate and save to db

   // get last inserted user_id, say in $user_id

   header("Location: /users/$user_id");
}
```

That way, the browser redirects and you won't have problem with say, double registration, whenever the user hits refresh.

Comment: I have been seeing this links everywhere. do you know any sample code for this?

Comment: It could be more useful if you posted more than a link in your answer. You're a 14k rep user, you know what a good answer should look like.

Comment: @Parthi04 edited my answer, probably similar to the one above though

Answer (score 3):

After saving to your database, reload your page:

```
if ($_POST) {
  // Save $_POST to database and other stuffs

  // Reload current page to discard $_POST
  header('Location: my_page.php');
}
```

That's called PRG or [Post/Reload/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get)

Comment: @Parthia consider accepting this answer if it worked for you. Click the large green hollow tick mark beneath the answer's vote count.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `unset($var)` to unset a variable. However, I think the issue is with the browsers; some of them try to be smart and will remember form data regardless when you refresh the page. If you hit "go" or "enter" on the URL bar it does a "true" refresh though.

Comment: That's not the solution.  Don't rely on the client to do a "true" refresh.

Comment: @Truth Where did I say the client should do a "true" refresh? I simply explained what he could do. At least at the time of my post, there were no details; he could have been debugging for all we know.